# Trouble using predict with linear model in R

Tags: r

I have a simple problem but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I am using `predict` to estimate values from a fitted linear model.  The following code works correctly:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6)
y <- c(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36)
model <- lm(y ~ x)
predict(model, newdata = data.frame(x=7))
```

However, when I use the same data for x and y, but in a dataframe, it does not work.  For example,

```
df2 <- structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), y = c(1, 4, 9, 16, 25,36)), 
                 .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
model <- lm(df2$y ~ df2$x)
predict(model, newdata = data.frame(x=7))
```

throws the error:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 6 rows
```

I am using the same exact data and am expecting the same answer.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
model = lm(y ~ x, data = df2)
predict(model, newdata = data.frame(x = 7))
```

The problem is the way you specified the formula.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, worked perfectly!  Now I will try with my real data!

Comment: It turned out that my issue resulted from using colnames to rename the dataframe columns before fitting lm.  the df2$y and df$x errors were introduced somewhere during my attempts to solve that underlying issue.  At any rate, the problem is now solved and I thank you again very much for your help Fernando.