# error when trying to predict from simple linear regression

Tags: r, lm

I have two variables `G` and `Y` that are correlated; each variable has 12 values. I compute the correlation and fit a linear regression model called `rg`. Now I want to use this model to predict new values for a second variable called `GP`. I want to get the `Y` values that correspond with each `GP` value. `GP` has 5 values.
When I do the prediction I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 5 rows but variables found have 12 rows
```

How can I apply the model to `GP`?, Does `GP` need to have 12 values? I suppose not. Is there any option in `predict.lm` to do this?

```
G<-c(20,25,21,30,22,23,19,24,21,23,28,27)
I<-c(229,235,230,242,231,233,226,232,230,232,238,236)

#diagrama de dispersion
qqplot(G,I)

#regression
rg<-lm(I ~ G)
summary(rg)
coef(rg[1])

#coeficiente de correlaciÃ³n
cor(G,I)
cp<-cor(G,I,method = c("pearson"))
cs<-cor(G,I,method = c("spearman"))


 # newdata
GP <- c(30,32,34,36,38)

# predecir el valor de ingresos para estos valores
X1<-data.frame(GP)

Y_pred <- predict.lm(rg,X1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the `predict` method, the names of the `newdata` data frame need to match the variables in the formula.

```
G <- c(20,25,21,30,22,23,19,24,21,23,28,27)
I <- c(229,235,230,242,231,233,226,232,230,232,238,236)
```

Pack the data into a data frame (names are taken automatically from the variable names): it's better practice to use the `data` argument rather than pulling the values from the global workspace.

```
dd <- data.frame(G,I)
rg <- lm(I ~ G, data=dd)
```

New data:

```
GP <- c(30,32,34,36,38)
pdata <- data.frame(G=GP)  ## same name as in original model
```

Note that if you don't rename the variable (`data.frame(GP)`) you'll get a data frame with a single variable `pdata$GP`, not one containing `pdata$G` (try it and see) - then R will complain that it can't find the `G` variable. (Note that `predict` can be used in much more complex situations where there are a large number of variables ...)

```
(Y_pred <- predict(rg,pdata))
##       1        2        3        4        5 
## 240.9580 243.4903 246.0227 248.5550 251.0874
```

Related (although maybe not *exact* duplicate): [Trouble using predict with linear model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122972/trouble-using-predict-with-linear-model-in-r/23123062#23123062) .

Comment: what's different data.frame(G=GP) and data.frame(GP)
 could you tell briefly .thanks

Comment: The column names of the newdata argument to `predict` need to match the RHS names in the formula used when making the lm-object. `data.frame(GP)` doesn't do that;  `data.frame(G=GP)` does.